# Textbox copy paste handling for numbers vs varchar data

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, winforms, textbox

I have thousands of text boxes in my winforms application.

I want to disable copy pasting for text boxes for numeric values for text boxes which should allow only numbers (integers).

For ex:

```
Employee number: 1234567
```

1. I tried setting false to the ShortcutsEnabled  property of text box , it completely stops disabling the entire copy & paste, which i don't want, i want to allow copy pasting for numbers.
2. I can get data from clipboard

> Clipboard.GetText();

and check whether

> Int32.TryParse

to check number/string.

Is there any general approach that i can use instead of going and pinning the code for each code or use regex expression ?

Comment: Can I know the reason behind disabling copy paste only for non-numeric... If it is to avoid validation, I will not recommend you go by that approach, as it will not be user friendly...  Instead you can use a validator for the same.

Answer (score 1):

Use a MaskedTextBox or NumericUpDown instead of a TextBox.

Answer (score 0):

Once simple approach to not disabling at all is to just use a numeric [masked textbox](http://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.windows.forms.maskedtextbox%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) that way bad input (non-numeric) will be rejected. Not only for copypaste but for direct input also.

Comment: How do i do it? there are already text boxes inside the application, do i change everything via design mode? which i don't way.

Answer (score 0):

Use TextChanged event and check the validate of the current text in it 
and if you are going to use that textbox in many win forms so I suggest you create an advance user control of TextBox and overide its TextChanged method.